# JWplayer Related Videos onclick link

Tags: javascript, json, jwplayer

Is there a way to navigate to another page when clicking the related videos in jwplayer? 
The link I need is already in the .json file with the tag link but it doesn't seem to be working.

My jwplayer configuration is as follows:

```
related: {
                    file: "videos.json",
                    onclick: "link",
                    oncomplete: 'autoplay',
                    autoplaytimer: 10
                }
```

My videos.json file returns the following:

```
"file":"24794.mp4",
"image":"24794.jpg",
"title":"Video Title",
"mediaid":"24794",
"link":"media.aspx?id=24794"
```

Is there something I'm missing?

I can't find documentation regarding the link tag anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried by passing the link value to href of an anchor tag?

Comment: It is solved now. All I did was remove the properties `oncomplete: 'autoplay', autoplaytimer: 10` and it started working. I guess the link field won't work if you have autoplay on. Thanks!